# How do i let the user input text in German / French for a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

Is there a way that I can let the end user type text in German / French in a text box for a c# asp.net website. Is there any available solution for the same,

Thank You

Comment: This is a bit vague. The textbox or ASP program don't care what language the end user uses. What exactly is the issue you have (try to post an example).

Comment: Sorry about that. I was referring to something like the tranliteration functionality in gmail.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to read this:

http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: I was referring to something like the tranliteration functionality in gmail

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about transliterating from German/French into English?  If so, that doesn't make much sense.  Transliteration is used to convert one system of text/writing into another, like Greek to English or German to Chinese.  With French, German, and English, there is no need to transliterate because they all use the same alphabet/writing system.

Was your question more about how to add a transliteration feature a la Google and you just used French and German as an example?